# [SMIC]Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS(20170831/dswload-378)

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, ssd

My PC Config:

AMD Ryzen 5 2400G 3.6GHz 4 cores

16GB Corsair (8GB DDR4 2800MHz X2)

Motherboard: X470 Gaming Plus (MS-7B79)

SSD 250GB Western Digital

OS Ubuntu 18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 but as soon as the bootable pendrive starts I get stuck at the below image. Not sure how should I proceed.

[Ubuntu bootup errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FAk1.jpg)

I even selected the open to check drive for defects, after the completion is said, found error in 19 files.

How do I fix those errors

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand what is happening here?